# How to play audio in ear speaker in ios?

Tags: ios, audio, media-player, avfoundation

I am working on fake call App

For an example : [Running App](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/fake-call-universal-edition/id460814994?mt=8)

So I need to do this thing :

**how to play audio in ear speaker in iphone, in which I have to play sound in ear speaker**

like : **InComing Call** , a sound come from ear speaker ?

Please suggest me, If it is possible ?

Comment: Eh ? Doesn't all audio come through the headphones if you have them plugged in ?

Comment: @Ohnomycoco : I edit the question , please have a look on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setDelegate:self];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];


UInt32 audioRouteOverride = kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_None;

AudioSessionSetProperty (
                         kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute,
                         sizeof (audioRouteOverride),
                         &audioRouteOverride
                         );
```